# Problems with column alignment in the `lstlisting` environment

Tags: listings

I'm having some problems with the column alignment in the `lstlisting` environment provided by `listings.sty`.

In fixed-width column alignment mode, whatever the typeface being used, listings are supposed to be presented with one character per column, where the columns have uniform widths (which may be set by the author). However, I find this not actually to be the case with certain input.

**Minimal example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[columns=fixed]
columnar alignment maligned multiple narrow characters?
1234 6789 1234 6789 1234 6789 1234 6789 1234 6789 1234
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image: result of lstlisting environment with improper column alignment]

Note that the second line is exactly one character shorter than the first, which is observed at the far right-hand side. However, the alignment in the middle is somewhat ruined at the occurance of every `l` character (ambiguous alignment of `u` in `columnar` with `3` or `4`; ambiguous alignment of `i`, `g`, and `n` in `alignment` with `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`; *etc.*). This problem is not helped by tweaking the alignment, by *e.g.* replacing `fixed` with `{[l]fixed}` for the column alignment.

Is this a known problem? Is there any fix for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the expected/default output for `columns=fixed` in an `lstlisting` environment. From the [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf):

> Now, the fixed format puts `n` characters into a box of width `n` x
>   `base width`, where the `base width` is `0.6em` in the example. The
>   format shrinks and stretches the space between the characters to make
>   them fit the box.

That is, the alignment is not meant to consistent across lines within the listing. Rather, the chunks of code is placed in boxes and the spacing is modified with no regard for anything else except the box width. Even the example presented in the documentation (page 19) exhibits this behaviour:

[image: Listings package documentation example]

Notice the misaligned `i` in **`write`** (line 1) and `print` (line 2) due to the wider **`w`**.

Even if you modified your minimal example to the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[columns=fixed]
colu mnar alig nmen tmal igne dmul tipl enar rowc hara cters?
1234 6789 1234 6789 1234 6789 1234 6789 1234 6789 1234
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

attempting to align the listing column-wise, the output looks better, but still has the same issues you mention:

[image: Modified listings example]

Notice the misalignment between `mnar` and `6789` (due to `m`); `tmal` and `1234` (again due to `m`); `rowc` and `6789` (due to `w`), etc.

The **only** way around this is to use a mono-spaced font for your entire listing, using (say) `basicstyle=\ttfamily`:

[image: Basicstyle=ttfamily in listings]

Comment: Hmm. What you're describing sounds an awful lot like the `flexible` spacing option. "*Common to all is that the input characters are translated into a sequence of basic output units*"; but surely what counts as a unit differs between the four alignment options, as otherwise the horrible spacing in the example text for the documentation (*e.g.* the words `MEN` and `WOMEN`) would not occur; even in my question, there's an odd space just before the `n` in `columnar` which should not occur if it's of one block. Are you quite sure that the blocks are **meant** to be computed on the syntactic level?

Comment: Basically, what I am asking is this –– this behaviour is obviously known, because you (at least) are taking it for granted that this is normal, and are able to use the documentation itself as evidence. Does anyone view this behaviour as **desirable**, that the `lstlisting` ruins the spacing between characters if you use `fixed` spacing, but doesn't do it well enough to **successfully** achieve columnar alignment? Or is this an issue which is somehow famously difficult to solve? Basically, I'm asking: is it worth addressing it as a bug to the package maintainer?

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it seems to explain what my problem is; although I'm unhappy with the fact that the problem exists, because it essentially defeats the purpose of the various spacing options in `listings.sty`.

Comment: Regardless of the outcome here, it is definitely advisable to follow up with the package maintainer(s). They would have the best idea whether it could be included in future releases, whether a temporary fix exists, or even whether there are others that have expressed similar interests.